# Best way to check database and execute operations every minute?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have an eCommerce app. I have an Item entity and whenever that item's end date time is equal to current time, the Item's status should change ( I also need to execute other SQL operations such as inserting a row to a table)

Basically, I want to execute an SQL operation that checks the database and changes entities every minute.

I have a few ideas on how to implement this:

- Schedule a job in my linux server that checks the db every minute
- Use sp_executesql (Transact-SQL) or DBMS Scheduler
- Have a thread running in my Java backend to check db and execute operations.

I am very new to this, so I don't have any idea how to implement this. What is the most efficient implementation that takes into account scalability performance?

Other information: database is SQL Server, server is Linux, backend is Java Spring Boot.

Comment: You can try the Quartz scheduler which will execute on specified time, i.e. every minute, hour ... and so on. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: *Backend is Java Spring Boot* - Due to caching it may be wise to accommodate for this.

Comment: Much simpler solution, don't store this status. Just display "elapsed" if the end date time is before the current time, and "OK" if it isn't.

Comment: @JBNizet I would also need to execute other operations in the db during end datetime so that isn't a solution

Comment: @ScaryWombat What do you mean?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Thanks for this! I will look into it

Comment: if what you need to do is purely SQL related operations, you should just schedule the job in SQL Server Agent

Comment: If you have a Java app that utilizes caching and an external app updates the DB, the changes may not be visible to the Java app as the data that is being used by Java may be coming from the cache

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/stmtcach.htm#CBHFBIDB

Comment: Thanks @ScaryWombat! Looking into this right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run a script after an insert or update, you can consolidate all that complex logic (e.g. insert rows in other tables, update the status column, etc.) in a trigger:

Here's a sample table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), start_time DATETIME, end_time DATETIME, 
    status VARCHAR(25))
```

And a sample insert/update trigger for that table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER u_t1 
ON t1
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t1
    SET status = CASE WHEN inserted.end_time = inserted.start_time 
        THEN 'same' ELSE 'different' END 
    FROM t1 
    INNER JOIN inserted ON t1.id = inserted.id

    -- do anything else you want!
    -- e.g. 
    -- INSERT INTO t2 (id, status) SELECT id, status FROM inserted
END
GO
```

Insert a couple test records:

```
INSERT INTO t1 (start_time, end_time) 
VALUES 
    (GETDATE(), GETDATE() - 1), -- different
    (GETDATE(), GETDATE())      -- same
```

Query the table after the inserts:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
```

See that the status is calculated correctly:

```
id  start_time              end_time                status
1   2018-07-17 02:53:24.577 2018-07-16 02:53:24.577 different
2   2018-07-17 02:53:24.577 2018-07-17 02:53:24.577 same
```

If your only goal is to update the status column based on other values in the table, then a computed column is the simplest approach; you just supply the formula:

```
create table t1 (id int identity(1,1), start_time datetime, end_time datetime, 
status as 
    case 
        when start_time is null then 'start null' 
        when end_time is null then 'end null' 
        when start_time < end_time then 'start less' 
        when end_time < start_time then 'end less' 
        when start_time = end_time then 'same' 
        else 'what?' 
    end
)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to computed columns, will implement this using @Formula in hibernate. I will not consider this as accepted answer tho because i also have to execute other sql operations on end datetime (not just changing status). Thanks!

Comment: Np! Updated my answer with a trigger example too. Good luck. and welcome to SQL!